# "Set" of answers from a variable to array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, variables

I am new to the programming world. In-fact, I started Python, just today.So, here is the problem:
I have got a huge number of answers from a variable. And I need to convert them to an array. I have looked at converting strings to array, strings to lists, int to lists etc. But nothing works. Please help.
Thank you for your responses.

```
>> g=v+p
>> g=str(g)
>> print g

-61.0
0
0
0
0
0
-57.0
-60.0
-56.0
0
0
0
0
0
0
-55.0
0
-57.0
-65.0
0
0
0
-54.0
0
0
0
-60.0
0
0
0
0
0
0
-54.0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
-57.0
-50.0
0
-57.0
0
0
0
-57.0
0
0
-56.0
-62.0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
-54.0
-59.0
0
0
0
0
-57.0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
-50.0
0
0
0
0
0
-55.0
0
0
0
-59.0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
-49.0
```

Comment: `array = map(int, g.split())` in python 2 or `array = list(map(int, g.split()))` in python 3

Comment: Where did you get `v` and `p`?  Were they strings?

Comment: @dmg It must be an answer not comment

Comment: @howaboutNO it should have been `float` so it's not a proper answer

Comment: Thank you for the reply guys.
@dmg: I still didn't get the array. I am getting an error that says, "invalid literal for int() with base 10: "

Comment: @JohnZwinck : v and p are other variables. No, they aren't strings, yet.

Comment: @PruthulRavindranath use `g.strip().split()` instead of `g.split()`. And also, don't use `int`, use `float`.

Comment: If I do that, I am getting an answer like: [-70.0]
[0.0]
[-64.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[-56.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[-61.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[-57.0]
[-60.0]
[-56.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]


But what I need is something like : [-70.0  0.0 -64.0 0.0.......-61.0....]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would split strings with a newline separator:

```
>>> value = "-23\n0\n0\n34"
>>> print value
-23
0
0
34
>>> value.split('\n')
['-23', '0', '0', '34']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I do that, I am getting an answer like: [-70.0] [0.0] [-64.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [-56.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [-61.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [-57.0] [-60.0] [-56.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] But what I need is something like : [-70.0 0.0 -64.0 0.0.......-61.0....]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert `g` to a list of numbers, I suggest this way:

```
map(float, g.split())
```

What this does is split `g` on whitespace, giving you a list of one element per line, then "map" those values (which are still strings) using the `float()` function.  The result is a list of floating-point numbers.